# SQLAlchemy - Can't update table using NULL for primary key value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a query which should create a License instance and part of it looks like it:

```
license_obj = license_db.License()
license_db.Session.add(license_obj)
license_obj.start_date = license['start_date']
license_obj.expiry_date = license['expiry_date']
```

I also have added a license_status relationship and license_status_id which points to LicenseStatus model

When I try to bind default value for license_status_id like below:

```
license_db.license_status_id = int(license_db.LicenseStatus.active().id)
```

then I get an error:

```
"Can't update table "
FlushError: Can't update table using NULL for primary key value
```

but when I try to assign integer manually, like shown below, then it works:

```
license_db.license_status_id = 1
```

What's causing the problem?

If I print license_db.LicenseStatus.active().id then I get int equal 1 which is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `license_db.session` after you set the license end date instead of the second line.

Comment: Moving license_db.Session.add(license_obj) to the end of the code solved my issue :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this error is quite misleading.
I got this and it turns out the problem is one of the columns marked as a Foreign Key to another table is null. Not the one marked as Primary Key, it's just a Foreign Key.